# How to get user information in Socket.IO

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets

Hi everyone I have this problem hope anyone can help.
So when user is login I will have that client id using socket.But after I have that id how can I retrieve the `user_id` field in database.I have install MySql in NodeJS.

Here is my `server.js` file

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );
var dateFormat = require('date-format');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );
var io = socket.listen( server );
var connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
    host        : 'localhost',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : '',
    database    : 'freelancer'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
});


io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    //get user id using client.id
    console.log( "New client id " + client.id );

});


server.listen( 8080 );
```